# Setting corresponding color for a barplot with lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I want to create a [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjEvf.jpg) consisting of grouped bars and corresponding lines - showing an evolution over time. What I am struggeling with is to assign the lines the same color as the bars have. What I do is

```r
gplot(subset(Panel_stats, Panel %in% Panel_Plot),aes(x=year,fill=Approach)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=PD_MEAN*100), position="dodge",stat="identity") + 
  geom_line(position=position_dodge(width=1.0),aes(y=DR_MEAN*100,group=Approach),size=2) + 
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=1.0),aes(y=DR_MEAN*100,group=Approach),size=3)+ 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

What must I do? I am looking for some sort of "automated" solution, ie. colors for both plots are assigned by the sequence of colors in the palette.

Thanks in advance,

Stefan

[The plot so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjEvf.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add a sample of your data frame with ```dput()``` and mention the variables you want to use for plotting.

Comment: See ggplot2. I recommend:
http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/32-r-graphics-essentials/

We will not be able to help you without providing your data.

Comment: You haven't told ggplot that you want to map the line colours to the variable `Approach`. To fix this, try changing your `geom_line` call to `geom_line(position = position_dodge(width = 1.0), aes(y = DR_MEAN * 100, group = Approach, color = Approach), size = 2)` .

Comment: @AllanCameron works, it's also possible to put `color = Approach` in the initial call to `ggplot()`. This would eliminate the need for `group = Approach`.

Comment: Allan CAmeron got the solution. I understand now better (intuitively) how it works. Thank you for that quick solution!

Answer (score -1):

Allan Cameron solved it (see in the comments to the questions). Thanks

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.